# Rendering eye-candy bar charts with PHP: tools / best practices

Tags: php, charts

We are using Google Charts for render the chart images, but 500 requests/day became not enough. What PHP classes/frameworks are worth looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/) and [GraPHPite](http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/) are the most developed open-source packages available. I recommend GraPHPite in particular, it has a somewhat better API and produces better looking graphs.

**Edit:** I recently developed a small [graphing library](http://www.binpress.com/app/analytics-and-graphing-with-php-sql/851) for fetching database data, process it with PHP and create Google Analytics style interactive graphs from it (uses [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to render the graphs on the client side). It's basically a complete server/client solution to turning your database tables into graphs.

Comment: Thanks, JpGraph seems to be quite flexible and powerful.

Comment: GraPHPite has not been updated since 2004 and by default works quite badly with modern PHP versions. Would not recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

The Google Chart API no longer has a 500 request/day limit. I recall this changed a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 0):

While not a PHP solution, we're using [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/) for the graphs within our application. They're Flash based, but look fantastic and allow your users to zoom in to the graph further. Graphs are drawn simply by generating XML with your data.